# Как задать через функцию JavaScript значение "data./значение/" которое нужно получить из JSON массива?

Tags: javascript, json

Сначала значения из массива JSON "вытягивались" переменными:

```
var login = data.login,
    name = data.name,
    avatar_url = data.avatar_url,
    bio = data.bio;
```

и помещались в HTML с помощью JavaScript:

```
$('#avatar').html('');
var avatarImg = '<img src=' + avatar_url + ' class="img-circle" >';
$('#avatar').append(avatarImg);

$('#name').html('');
var name = '<span>' + name + '</span>';
$('#name').append(name);

$('#login').html('');
var login = '<span>' + login + '</span>';
$('#login').append(login);

$('#bio').html('');
if (bio == null) {
    var bio = '<a href="#">Add a bio</a>';
}else {
    var bio = '<p>' + bio + '</p>'
}
```

Все работает отлично, но для оптимизации хотел задействовать функцию, которая вытягивала бы значение из data и помещала это значение куда нужно. К примеру:

```
var templ = function (item) {
    var itemId = '#' + item;
    var itemData = data.item;
    $(itemId).html('');
    var itemTypeTempl = '<span>' + itemData + '</span>';
    $(itemId).append(itemTypeTempl);
};

templ('login');
```

Но `var itemData = data.item` не возвращает *data.login* как мне бы хотелось. Пробовал `var itemData = 'data.' + item` - но возвращает строку *"data.login"*, а мне нужно вытянуть данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно пытаетесь извлечь значение из массива data по ключу item. Попробуйте так

```
 var templ = function (item) {
      var itemId = '#' + item;
      var itemData = data[item];
      $(itemId).html('');
      var itemTypeTempl = '<span>' + itemData + '</span>';
      $(itemId).append(itemTypeTempl);
 };

 templ('login');
```

и еще я бы предложил упростить

```
 var templ = function (item) {
      $('#' + item).html('<span>' + data[item] + '</span>');
 };

 templ('login');
```

Comment: Аж стыдно, что я так "затупил"... Спасибо!